# I want to know if my validation script is secure enough against user error or attack

Tags: javascript, php

I have this as my registration validation code. I want to follow the pattern i used for my javascript on the server side. All i want to know is if my script is enough to counter any user error or attack. Thanks

```
function regvalidate() {
    var gender = $j("#gen").val();
    var surname = $j("#nsn").val();
    var firstname = $j("#nfn").val();
    var othername = $j("#notn").val();
    var username = $j("#un").val();
    var phone = $j("#tel").val();
    var password = $j("#pw").val();
    var rpassword = $j("#rpw").val();
    var sorigin = $j("#sor").val();
    var age = $j("#age").val();
    var churchname = $j("#cname").val();
    var churchname2 = churchname.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_| \-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/ ]/gi,'');
    var schoolname = $j("#sn").val();
    var schoolname2 = schoolname.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_| \-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/ ]/gi,'');
    var secquestion = $j("#sq").val();
    var secanswer = $j("#sqa").val();
    var secanswer2 = secanswer.replace(/\s/g,"");
    var originalcaptcha = $j("#ocaptcha").text();
    var usercaptcha = $j("#ucaptcha").val();    
    var chkb = $j("#chkb").prop("checked");

    if (gender!='female' && gender!='male') {
        alert("please select a valid gender");
    } else if (!surname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,50}$/)) {
        alert("please enter a valid surname. Alphabets only and no space.");
    } else if (!firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,50}$/)) {
        alert("please enter a valid firstname. Alphabets only and no space.");
    } else if (!othername.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,50}$/)) {
        alert("please enter a valid other name. Alphabets only and no space.");
    } else if (!username.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}$/)) {
        alert("enter a valid username please. Alphanumeric supported only. Min: 4 Max: 20");
    } else if (!password.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/)) {
        alert("password should only contain alphabets or numbers. Min: 5 Max: 20");
    } else if (pw!=rpassword) {
        alert("password is not the same");
    } else if (!phone.match(/^[0-9]{11,13}$/)) {
        alert("please enter a valid phone number");
    } else if (!sorigin.match(/^[a-zA-Z.]{3,15}$/)||sorigin.length<3) {
        alert("select your state");
    } else if (!age.match(/^[0-9]{2}$/)) {
        alert("input your correct age. Atleast Ten years of age");
    } else if (!churchname.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9',.\-_\(\) ]{13,100}$/)) {
        alert("enter a valid church name. Do not abbreviate!");
    } else if (churchname.match(/(.)\1{3,}/)) {
        alert("enter a valid church name");
    } else if (churchname2.length<13) {
        alert("church name too short");
    } else if (!schoolname.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9',.\-_\(\) ]{13,100}$/)) {
        alert("enter a valid school name. Do not abbreviate!");
    } else if (schoolname2.length<13) {
        alert("school name too short");
    } else if (schoolname.match(/(.)\1{3,}/)) {
        alert("enter a valid school name");
    } else {
        $j("#reghloading").show();
        $j.post("processorthis.php",$j("#regform").serialize(),function(data) {
            $j(".regresult").html(data);
        }).done(function() {
            $j("#reghloading").hide();
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("unable to process your request now. Check back later");
        });
    }; 
return false;
}
```

Comment: Correct your question.

Comment: well, your site is going to reject Malcolm X for no good reason, and discriminates against centenarians

Comment: @seybanks hey there, it took some time to fix your formatting, there's an option that allows you to indent entire blocks of code (copy and paste from your text editor into answer, then select *all* the code and press the `{}` once in the editor).

Comment: Yea.. I Don't really need a very old person on the site

Comment: You can register with an invalid age: "00" seems to match your regex but is not a correct value - I guess -

Comment: Thanks @didier ...#NOTED